# got error when 'npm install' ionic 2 app

Tags: npm, ionic2, ionic3, npm-install

got error when 'npm install' , please help .
i got this problem when i try to npm install ionic 2 app,about last year project
but when i try to build new app using ionic start,got no problem
please guide me how to solve this because im new to ionic.

```
> node-sass@3.10.1 install E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Start downloading binary at https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.10.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node": ode:
HTTP error 404 Not Found
Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
or configure npm proxy via
      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\ionic\\Section Code (Finished)\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd E:\ionic\Section Code (Finished)\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hafez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-10T00_09_01_869Z-debug.log
```

This are my node version

v8.11.1

npm version

v8.11.1

Comment: try this ->   rm -rf node_modules,
rm package-lock.json,
npm install  **may be it resolve your problem**

Comment: same error , idont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step

1.rm -rf node_modules

2.rm package-lock.json

3.npm i --unsafe-perm=true